# How to create button in navbar with icon-bars with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

I am new to bootstrap. I want to create a button in navbar that has three icon-bars.

Here is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn-default pull-right">        
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
</button>
```

Above creates a button but it's very small and has no icon-bars. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your code around the button correct? Maybe if it is not correctly in a .navbar-header it will display incorrectly. See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DngbnBNBbo) for an example of correct markup

Comment: The button is not placed in the navbar-header, but even if I put it there it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `navbar-toggle` class and an id, then in your css target that id and make the `display:block;`

something like:

html:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn-default pull-right navbar-toggle" id="hamburgerIcon">        
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>    
</button>
```

css:

```
#hamburgerIcon{
  display:block;
}
```